# HDD Stopped Responding

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, mbr, bootsector

I have an external 500GB hard drive containing a WD Scorpio Black, used all as one partition, encrypted with BitLocker and runs very well.

This morning I connected it to my PC, it asked for BitLocker password, I entered it and then the drive shows an open lock as it was successfully unlocked, but without showing the bar showing used and free disk space as usual.
I even removed the drive from the external case and connected directly to SATA ports.

When I try to access it shows me this:

[image]

The problem is that when unlocking BitLocker it unlocks without a problem. When scanning for bad sectors with DRevitalize v2.42 it scans with no problems.
Now how to get back my nearly 300GB of important personal and professional files?

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully you have more than one backup of critical files.

Comment: You will need to restore from a backup, you have indeed severed from likely an unrecoverable HDD failure, something cause the file system on the HDD to be lost.  *Its likely as simple as the sectors that contain that information went bad.*  Use something other then DRevitalize to verify the health of your HDD.

Comment: I will be honest the description of `DRevitalize` screams "snake oil" software can't "repair" physical defects on magnetic media.  If they are physical defects, then outside of physically repairing them, they can't be fixed.  Perhaps the product description is just poor, I don't know, but it indicates to me something is fishy.